# Unable to find libsvml.a in the base toolkit for mac

Tags: intel, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I am using OneApi base toolkit for Mac, I was looking for libsvml.a in the library but it is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file which you are looking for doesn't come with oneAPI Base toolkit but you can get it by downloading oneAPI HPC toolkit. So please try downloading the oneAPI HPC toolkit and you can find the libsvml.a file under this location /opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.3/mac/compiler/lib